# Syntax sugar for querying a Python list which element occurs first

Tags: python, list, syntactic-sugar

I have a list of many elements.

I care about two of its elements, `a` and `b`.

I don't know the order of the list, nor do I want to sort it.

Is there a nice one-liner that will return `True` if `a` occurs before `b` and false otherwise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Edit: Rewritten to check more cases

OK, so this problem needs a bit more work. Mark Byers is completely right in that my first test only covered cases where the result would be `True`. This is especially relevant because we need exception handlers for the other solutions. So I've gone into a bit more detail:

```
stmts = {
"Mark Byers: ": "x = l.index(a) < l.index(b)",
"jcollado: ": """try:
    x = bool(l.index(b, l.index(a)))
except ValueError:
    x = False""",
"Greg Hewgill: ": """try:
   x = b in l[l.index(a):]
except ValueError:
   x = False"""
}

setups = ["a = 80; b = 90; l = list(range(100))", 
          "a = 5; b = 10; l = list(range(100))", 
          "a = 90; b = 80; l = list(range(100))",
          "a = 10; b = 5; l = list(range(100))"]

import timeit
for se in setups:
    print(se)
    for st in stmts:
        print(st, timeit.timeit(stmt=stmts[st], setup=se))
    print()
```

results in:

```
a = 80; b = 90; l = list(range(100))
Mark Byers:  5.760545506106019
Greg Hewgill:  3.454101240451526     # Tie!
jcollado:  3.4574156981854536        # Tie!


a = 5; b = 10; l = list(range(100))
Mark Byers:  1.0853995762934794      # Close runner-up!
Greg Hewgill:  1.7265326426395209
jcollado:  1.0528704983320782        # Winner!

a = 90; b = 80; l = list(range(100))
Mark Byers:  5.741535600372806
Greg Hewgill:  3.623253643486848     # Winner!
jcollado:  4.567104188774817

a = 10; b = 5; l = list(range(100))
Mark Byers:  1.0592141197866987      # Winner!
Greg Hewgill:  4.73399648151641
jcollado:  4.77415749512712
```

So the efficiency gain from jcollado's method is mostly eaten up by the cost of the exception handler (expecially if it triggers). All three solutions win (or tie with the winner) half of the time, so which method works best on your actual data is hard to say. Perhaps you might want to go with the one that's easiest to read.

Comment: I didn't know about the timeit module. I love StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't take into account the time needed to create another list object when using the `l[l.index(n):]` approach.

Comment: @jcollado: That's probably it. Congratulations on finding a more efficient answer than two opponents with > 300k reputation! :)

Comment: All your tests only test the situation where the result is `True`. What if the answer is `False`? You tested `a = 5, b = 10` but please also try `a = 10, b = 5` too, just to make it a fair test.

Comment: @MarkByers: Excellent point, and after doing that, I'd favor your version because of better readability and comparable performance over all cases.

Answer (score 9):

In the interests of diversity, you could also:

```
b in l[l.index(a):]
```

This will be `True` if `a == b`. If you know that `a != b`,

```
b in l[l.index(a) + 1:]
```

Comment: How pythonic! The meaning would be totally confusing to a Java programmer. I love it!

Comment: In my Gale-Shapley implementation this example turns into `elif husband[w] in women[w][women[w].index(m):]:` ahahah!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `list.index`:

```
l.index(a) < l.index(b)
```

This of course assumes that both items are present in the list.

Answer (score 5):

Response from Mark Byers works fine, but it won't be very efficient if list is long and both elements are close to the end.

To traverse the list just once, you can use this:

```
l.index(b, l.index(a))
```

This is a one-liner as required, but you'll need to capture `ValueError` exception anyway.

Comment: Fastest, but if I get a ValueError (say `a` occurs after `b`) then I have to catch it like you said, increasing my lines! Thank you anyways :)

Comment: Actually, after Tim updated his new times above, I decided yours was the best answer despite having to add a try/except. So I changed my accepted answer to your answer. Thanks again!